# Backbone.js with a custom fetch URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set up a variant fetch method on my backbone model that will fetch the current model for a given user. This is available from the API on `/api/mealplans/owner/{username}/current`.

I have written the following model. I commented out the URL Root, as the prototype fetch call was simply using the `urlRoot` and I wanted to see if that was overriding the url parameter I passed in portions somehow.

```
var mealPlan = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: 'Meal Plan',
  //urlRoot: '/api/mealplans',
  defaults: {},
  fetchCurrent: function (username, attributes, options) {
    attributes = attributes || {};
    options = options || {};
    if (options.url === undefined) {
      options.url = "/api/mealplans/owner/" + username + "/current";
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, attributes, options);
  },
  validate: function (attributes) {
    // To be done
    return null;
  }
});
```

I've seen this done, in some variations in other places, such as at [backbone.js use different urls for model save and fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644767/backbone-js-use-different-urls-for-model-save-and-fetch) - In that case the code is slightly different (I started with that and broke it down to make it easier for me to read.)

The options object has the url parameter in it fine when I pass it to fetch, but then it seems to ignore it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was assuming the same parameters to fetch as to save - This is not the case.

The method signature for fetch ONLY takes 'options' and not 'attributes', hence the url parameter wasn't found.

The model code should look a bit more like this..

```
   var mealPlan = Ministry.Model.extend({

        name: 'Meal Plan',
        urlRoot: '/api/mealplans',

        defaults: {
        },

        fetchCurrent: function (username, options) {
            options = options || {};
            if (options.url === undefined) {
                options.url = this.urlRoot + "/owner/" + username + "/current";
            }

            return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        },

        validate: function (attributes) {
            // To be done
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I literally searched 100 topics, questions and posts for this answer! thank you so much!

Comment: No worries - I always try to answer the questions I post if I find out for myself just in case. I go nuts at times digging through unanswered online posts.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to override url() method, like below:

```
 var mealPlan = Ministry.Model.extend({

    name: 'Meal Plan',
    urlRoot: '/api/mealplans',

    //--> this gets called each time fetch() builds its url
    url: function () { 
        //call the parent url()
        var url=Backbone.Model.prototype.url.call(this);
        //here you can transform the url the way you need
        url += "?code=xxxx";
        return url;
    }
 ...
```

besides, in your example above I think there is a mistake and you should replace **fetchCurrent** by **fetch**

Comment: Should urlRoot be mentioned in the override?  It is not clear how the root is prepended to the "?code=xxxx" string.  Maybe `var url=Backbone.Model.prototype.urlRoot.call(this);`

Comment: No, it is a method from Model. the right way is url.call(). If you look at the source code you'll see the proper attribute is taken: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html